# MAF. Call from add-in side

Tags: c#, maf

I'm developing an application that provides plugins. I'm using Managed Add-In Framework for my aim. Is there a way to call host's method from add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you define an interface in the contract (and in both views) and then you create a concrete implementation of that interface on the host adapter side and pass that into a method on the addin.

One simple example would be having a logger interface (`ILogger`) and implementing a logger in the host view.  Then you could create a `AddInInitialize` method in your contract that takes an `ILogger`.  It can then call methods on that `ILogger` and it will go across the MAF boundry (cross process or not depending on your setup) to make the appropriate calls.

Comment: Do you have a example. I tried to follow your explations, but i got stucked.

Comment: I found this example https://clraddins.codeplex.com/releases/view/10199